# Need a regex that accepts any text that contains at least 3 alphabets

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression that accepts any string that contains at least 3 English alphabets. The alphabets can be anywhere in the string.

Test cases:

Should return `true` for:

```
abc
This is a test
This number 123 just $@!!.
123ABC289389798
```

Should return `false` for:

```
ab
ab213823897
```

EDIT: Sorry, I should clarify that it needs 3 English alphabets. The alphabets can be anywhere in the string.

Comment: What is an "Alphabet" to you ?

Comment: What do you mean by alphabet? You could use three regex in AND

Comment: @Jackopo: No, I don't think 3 regex helps in this case.

Comment: `match(/([a-z]{3,})/ig)` helps you?

Comment: I am guessing that "Alphabet" is used to mean alphabetic character - e.g. [A-Za-z]

Comment: @nhahtdh why not? A single regex would need to explicit all 6 permutations of alphabets (I think something like `.*[a-z].*[A-Z].*[1-9].*` repeated with an `|` changing the order. Is there an easiest way with only one regex?

Comment: @Jackopo that doesn't match with the passing examples given...

Comment: do the alphabetic characters need to be consecutive, or can they be spaced apart?

Comment: @Jackopo: Kind of depends on how you interpret the question... Check some of the answers below...

Comment: @penguat yes, I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z]
```

The [A-Za-z] matches any character from A-Z or from a-z. This regex guarantees that you have 3 of these characters. The .* matches any number of any character, so your three alpha characters can be consecutive or have anything before/after/in between.

Test it out at a regex tool like http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

You can also consolidate it like this:

```
([A-Za-z].*){3}
```

EDIT: replaced \w with [A-Za-z] and added explanation.

EDIT2: thanks @nhahtdh, removed .* from beginning and end since we only need a match, not coverage of the whole string.

Comment: FYI, you can remove the last `.*`, and you can even remove the first `.*`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want all letters to return true back to back, simply use:

```
[a-zA-Z]{3,}
```

This doesn't include spaces.

If you do not need to place these back to back, try this:

```
[a-zA-Z].*?[a-zA-Z].*?[a-zA-Z]
```

Comment: What are the `?` for? You already have the `*` quantifier. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

or perhaps :

```
/([a-z]|[A-Z]){3,}/
```

http://jsbin.com/oleseb/1/edit

Comment: hah, Yep.. That question has too many answers..., why would you need to place `/g`. Does the OP needs multiple matches?

Comment: Even if you didn't want to use the `i` flag, it makes more sense to use `[a-zA-Z]`, and put the parentheses outside the `{3,}` to capture the whole match, not every character

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
[a-zA-Z]{3,}
```

it will match, 3 or more of `a-z` & `A-Z` chars

Comment: This will only match if the 3 alphabet characters are consecutive. `3e4r4t` will not match. Don't know OP's intention, though.

Comment: They can be anywhere in the text

Comment: ^^^the test strings that OP gave, all pass with this `regex` http://rubular.com/r/ltD0bFv4JZ

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

```
string.replace(/[\W^\d]/g, '').length >= 3;
```

Comment: what's the advantage of doing it this way? will there be any non-alphabetic characters which pass?

Comment: You are removing all non-word characters, and digits, and `^` (which is redundant) which means all that is left is `A-Z`, `a-z` and **underscore**.